# Join multiple ranges when using conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I have a simple conditional formatting custom formula which highlights duplicate values in a column:

```
=countif(A:A,A1)>1
```

I have another column on another sheet (same workbook) which I would like to include in the search for duplicates. I can combine the ranges separately using the following formula:

```
=query({sheet1!A:A; sheet2!A:A},"where Col1 <>''")
```

but I can't get that formula to work in conditional formatting. What I have (which doesn't work), is:

```
=countif(query({sheet1!A:A; sheet2!A:A},"where Col1 <>''"),A1)>1
```

I don't understand how `"where Col1 <>''"` works or why I need it, but even so, the formula doesn't work.

The question is, how can I (using conditional formatting) highlight duplicate cells in column A, searching across multiple ranges for duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- when referencing another sheet in **conditional formatting**, you need to use **`INDIRECT`**
- conditional format rules are **per sheet** meaning that you need 1 separate rule per every sheet
- **`"where Col1 <>''"`** means to select only those rows from a query which are not empty in the 1st column
- to show duplicates between 2 ranges use this custom formula:

  ```
  =COUNTIF({A:A,INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:A")},A1)>1
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Oh that's just superb - thank you!